# Play game developed with HTML5, CSS and JavaScript without an internet connection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have developed a game using the technologies mentioned above, however I would like the game not to need a web server to play it, but to run as if it were a desktop application.

I have read that with node js you can create a local web server and with that to run the game, but I don't know how to achieve it.

The idea is that the game has an icon on the desktop and after executing it, it can be played, that is, everything is integrated and the person who has the game does not need to download external programs such as xampp.

Final note: is this possible for smartphones?

Comment: You do not need to use a web server to run this game if it is in your local machine.

Comment: can you make a more general explanation? The idea is to distribute the game and that people do not need plugins for example xampp to be able to play it.

Comment: whom do you want to distribute to? A small no. of people around you or the entire globe?

Comment: There you go: [How to make your app work offline with the power of JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-app-work-offline-with-the-power-of-javascript-685d968bcfbb/)

Comment: simply that whoever has it can play it, (The game is not multiplayer)

Comment: @aloneitan that does not work

Comment: In both cases (XAMPP and Node,js), your computer will be needed.

Comment: Why would it not @AD-1?

Comment: that is a service worker. It works for only one computer. It caches a website for one device. But @erik wants something else.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right @AD-1, I missed that part _"I have read that with node js you can create a local web server and with that to run the game"_

Comment: @AD-1 then not possible?

Comment: @erik, if you want a very small no. of people to use the game, you can use both XAMPP or node,js. Both will require your computer but the device which wants to use the game does not need XAMPP or node.js installed but they need to be connected to your wifi network.

Comment: I explain myself in another way, I use xampp to run my game locally, however I do not want to require this, I want my game to be played only need to click on its icon and then play, what I am looking for is to be able to integrate everything within the game so that the person who wants to play it does not need to download xampp, but only by downloading the game can play it.

Comment: the idea as such is to integrate everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is ElectronJS, it is a NodeJS library that lets you package browser code as a desktop app. It works for macOS, Linux, and Windows.

Website: https://electronjs.org

Edit: Also once the app is packaged and in your computer you won’t need an internet connection. Final note, it turns it into an actual app so like app for macOS and exe for windows. So they won’t need a web server on their computer to run it.